# tunneling to my private ip from outside network

Tags: ssh, ip-address, telnet, remote-access

i want to telnet or ssh my pc (mac) at home from my office. How can i do this ? the problem i'm using router with private ip .Gateway is 192.168.1.1 and my pc is 192.168.1.100. I  think i should be able to do this when i forward the port in the router setting. But the problem i don't have public ip. My isp only give my dynamic ip (DHCP) , my router's external ip is just another private ip which is connected to another gateway (another level of LAN) which of course i don't have any access. so is it still possible to get access using telnet to my computer ? i read about the reverse ssh but that only works if i have to setup the connection first from my pc. In my case now there's no body near my pc. i just turn it on so i can hopefully access it.

Is there any workaround ? or it's just impossible to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you don't have a stable IP, I can only think of two options:

#### VPN

Were you to make a VPN with your local network, and then connect to said VPN, it would give you access to everything on on the network.

#### Reverse SSH

With reverse SSH you make use of an external server, and set up a listening ssh session. Then, on the external server you can connect to the device behind the router without being bothered by firewalls/port forwarding/etc...

You could do this with:
Device on home network `ssh -f -N -R 1234:localhost:22 remote_user@remote.server.example`

- Where `1234` is the port that remote would use forward to the device
- `remote.server.example` is the remote's address

Then, on the remote server `ssh -p 1234 -t device_user@localhost`

Comment: I’d recommend you use an OpenVPN server with NO-IP to deal with Dynamic IP.